# Excel Macros repeating data in multiple rows while pasting to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have made a calculation sheet for my project. There are multiple inputs to this sheet. One of the variable is **i** which changes the results. Changing **i** changes row value which I want in `Missing Num` sheet. My aim is to copy and paste that row values from `Sheet 1` to `Missing Num` for every **i**.

I have written the code for copy and paste but for some reason, it is repeating values. Please look into this error. Attached is the screenshot.

```
Sub AddBigNumbers_1()
'Worksheets("Input Sheet").Range("B4:F4").Merge
'Range("B4").Value = "i=1"
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, i_max As Integer, j_max As Integer, k As Integer, i_min As Integer, l As Integer
'Call OptimizeCode_Begin
i = 0
j = 0
i_max = Range("D8").Value 'Max value of i that can be entered
j_max = 31 'Range of columns - 6 Num to 36 Num
i_min = Range("D5")
k = 0
For i = i_min To i_max Step 1
    Worksheets("Missing Num - Selec Pt").Range("C5").Value = Worksheets("Missing Num - Selec Pt").Cells(i + 3, 5).Value   'A3 cell is in which i value is stored

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False                  
            For j = 1 To j_max Step 1
                Worksheets("Missing Num - Selec Pt").Cells(3 + i, 5 + j).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(40, 3 + j).Value
                'RHS is original strip from which data has to be extracted & LHS where data has to be entered
            Next j
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        k = 0
Next i[Screenshot][1]
End Sub
```

Comment: Screenshot link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/15AQ6sFMUQxiZ9mmws2V8sP8_hLxZKmHI/view?usp=sharing
 for some reason, screenshot was not posted in question.

Comment: Just to make sure, you know this:  '.Cells(i + 3, 5).Value'  is looping through Column "E" right?

Comment: Just to make sure... `i_min = Range("D5")` is `i_min = Range("D5").Value2`, isn´t it?